# Как добавить к активному элементу класс .active?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, как добавить к активному элементу класс .active?

То есть мне нужно в блоке progressBarContainer к активному блоку добавить класс active?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    

    $(".slider").slick({
    infinite: true,
    arrows: false,
    dots: false,
    autoplay: false,
    speed: 800,
    fade: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    });

    //ticking machine
    var percentTime;
    var tick;
    var time = 1;
    var progressBarIndex = 0;

    $('.progressBarContainer .progressBar').each(function(index) {
        var progress = "<div class='inProgress inProgress" + index + "'></div>";
        $(this).html(progress);
    });

    function startProgressbar() {
        resetProgressbar();
        percentTime = 0;
        tick = setInterval(interval, 10);
    }

    function interval() {
        if (($('.slider .slick-track div[data-slick-index="' + progressBarIndex + '"]').attr("aria-hidden")) === "true") {
            progressBarIndex = $('.slider .slick-track div[aria-hidden="false"]').data("slickIndex");
            startProgressbar();
        } else {
            percentTime += 1 / (time + 5);
            $('.inProgress' + progressBarIndex).css({
                width: percentTime + "%"
            });
            if (percentTime >= 100) {
                $('.single-item').slick('slickNext');
                progressBarIndex++;
                if (progressBarIndex > 2) {
                    progressBarIndex = 0;
                }
                startProgressbar();
            }
        }
    }

    function resetProgressbar() {
        $('.inProgress').css({
            width: 0 + '%'
        });
        clearInterval(tick);
    }
    startProgressbar();
    // End ticking machine

    $('.progressBarContainer div').click(function () {
        clearInterval(tick);
        var goToThisIndex = $(this).find("span").data("slickIndex");
        $('.single-item').slick('slickGoTo', goToThisIndex, false);
        startProgressbar();
    });
    
        
});
```

```css
h3 {
  margin:5px 0; 
}

.sliderContainer {
  position: relative;
}

.slider {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 30px 50px 50px;
}

.slick-slide {
  background: #3a8999;
  color: white;
  padding: 80px 0 120px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica";
  text-align: center;
}

.slick-prev:before,
.slick-next:before {
  color: black;
}

.slick-dots {
  bottom: -30px;
}

.slick-slide:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #e84a69;
}

.progressBarContainer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  width:300px;
  left:150px;
}

.progressBarContainer div {
  display: block;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 5%;
  float: left;
  color: white;
}

.progressBarContainer div:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.progressBarContainer div span.progressBar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  display: block;
}

.progressBarContainer div span.progressBar .inProgress {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  width: 0%;
  height: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js" integrity="sha512-XtmMtDEcNz2j7ekrtHvOVR4iwwaD6o/FUJe6+Zq+HgcCsk3kj4uSQQR8weQ2QVj1o0Pk6PwYLohm206ZzNfubg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css" integrity="sha512-wR4oNhLBHf7smjy0K4oqzdWumd+r5/+6QO/vDda76MW5iug4PT7v86FoEkySIJft3XA0Ae6axhIvHrqwm793Nw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<!-- main slider -->
<div class="sliderContainer">
  <div class="slider single-item">
    <div class="slide">Slide1</div>
    <div class="slide">Slide2</div>
    <div class="slide">Slide3</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      
      
  <div class="progressBarContainer">
<!-- Как к активному item добавить рядом класс active? -->
    <div class="item">
      <h3>Slide 1</h3>
      <span data-slick-index="0" class="progressBar"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h3>Slide 2</h3>
      <span data-slick-index="1" class="progressBar"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h3>Slide 3</h3>
      <span data-slick-index="2" class="progressBar"></span>
    </div>
    </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end main slider -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё что вам нужно - это в конце функции `interval` добавить эти строчки:

```
$('.item.active').removeClass('active');
$('.item').eq(progressBarIndex).addClass('active');
```

Документация:

- [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/)
- [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)
- [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Первая строчка в первый раз ничего не сделает, но начиная со второго раза будет убирать активный класс

Вторая строка просто среди всех элементов с классом `item` выбирает `progressBarIndex`-ный элемент и добавляет ему активный класс

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $(".slider").slick({
    infinite: true,
    arrows: false,
    dots: false,
    autoplay: false,
    speed: 800,
    fade: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
  });

  //ticking machine
  var percentTime;
  var tick;
  var time = 1;
  var progressBarIndex = 0;

  $('.progressBarContainer .progressBar').each(function(index) {
    var progress = "<div class='inProgress inProgress" + index + "'></div>";
    $(this).html(progress);
  });

  function startProgressbar() {
    resetProgressbar();
    percentTime = 0;
    tick = setInterval(interval, 10);
  }

  function interval() {
    if (($('.slider .slick-track div[data-slick-index="' + progressBarIndex + '"]').attr("aria-hidden")) === "true") {
      progressBarIndex = $('.slider .slick-track div[aria-hidden="false"]').data("slickIndex");
      startProgressbar();
    } else {
      percentTime += 1 / (time + 5);
      $('.inProgress' + progressBarIndex).css({
        width: percentTime + "%"
      });
      if (percentTime >= 100) {
        $('.single-item').slick('slickNext');
        progressBarIndex++;
        if (progressBarIndex > 2) {
          progressBarIndex = 0;
        }
        startProgressbar();
      }
    }

    $('.item.active').removeClass('active');
    $('.item').eq(progressBarIndex).addClass('active');
  }

  function resetProgressbar() {
    $('.inProgress').css({
      width: 0 + '%'
    });
    clearInterval(tick);
  }
  startProgressbar();
  // End ticking machine

  $('.progressBarContainer div').click(function() {
    clearInterval(tick);
    var goToThisIndex = $(this).find("span").data("slickIndex");
    $('.single-item').slick('slickGoTo', goToThisIndex, false);
    startProgressbar();
  });


});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red !important;
}

h3 {
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.sliderContainer {
  position: relative;
}

.slider {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 30px 50px 50px;
}

.slick-slide {
  background: #3a8999;
  color: white;
  padding: 80px 0 120px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica";
  text-align: center;
}

.slick-prev:before,
.slick-next:before {
  color: black;
}

.slick-dots {
  bottom: -30px;
}

.slick-slide:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #e84a69;
}

.progressBarContainer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  left: 150px;
}

.progressBarContainer div {
  display: block;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 5%;
  float: left;
  color: white;
}

.progressBarContainer div:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.progressBarContainer div span.progressBar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  display: block;
}

.progressBarContainer div span.progressBar .inProgress {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  width: 0%;
  height: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js" integrity="sha512-XtmMtDEcNz2j7ekrtHvOVR4iwwaD6o/FUJe6+Zq+HgcCsk3kj4uSQQR8weQ2QVj1o0Pk6PwYLohm206ZzNfubg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css" integrity="sha512-wR4oNhLBHf7smjy0K4oqzdWumd+r5/+6QO/vDda76MW5iug4PT7v86FoEkySIJft3XA0Ae6axhIvHrqwm793Nw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<!-- main slider -->
<div class="sliderContainer">
  <div class="slider single-item">
    <div class="slide">Slide1</div>
    <div class="slide">Slide2</div>
    <div class="slide">Slide3</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>


      <div class="progressBarContainer">
        <!-- Как к активному item добавить рядом класс active? -->
        <div class="item">
          <h3>Slide 1</h3>
          <span data-slick-index="0" class="progressBar"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h3>Slide 2</h3>
          <span data-slick-index="1" class="progressBar"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h3>Slide 3</h3>
          <span data-slick-index="2" class="progressBar"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end main slider -->
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!